# how to reverse number in 4 digits(java)

Tags: java

This is my code down below;

```
 int reverse = 0;

     while( num != 0 )
      {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + num%10;
      num = num/10;

    }

    System.out.println(reverse);
```

if i input :1234 it will show 4321

but if i input 0044

it will output 44

i want to output 4400

what should i type in?

Comment: In every input you will have only 4 digit combination ???

Comment: how will this work in your mind? as numbers, inputs 0044 and 44 are identical. so you must take the inputs as strings, and reverse them as strings, or something else, instead of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Since leadig zeroes have no meaning in an int, you'll have to read your input as a String and reverse that String in order to keep the leading zeroes (and turn them into trailing zeroes).

Comment: they do have a meaning, they mean it's an Octal literal

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Only if they are hard-coded as literals. If you input to the following code `0034`, you'll get 34. `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int leadzero = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(leadzero);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your loop size, not your logic.
Assuming all your numbers are 4 digits, then

```
 int reverse = 0;

 int i;
 for( i = 0; i < 4 ; i++ )
  {
  reverse = reverse * 10;
  reverse = reverse + num%10;
  num = num/10;

}

System.out.println(reverse);
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

You might have to try working with string to achieve this. 
try the code below

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Reverse 
  {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
     StringBuilder number=new StringBuilder(in.next());
     System.out.println(number.reverse());
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

now if you want to find the difference between the reversed number and the input number

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Reverse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    String number=in.next();
    StringBuilder numbertoRev=new StringBuilder(number);
    try{
    int a=Integer.valueOf(number);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
       System.out.println("not a number :)");
       return;
    }
    int b=Integer.valueOf(numbertoRev.reverse().toString());
    System.out.println(b-a);
}
```

This is what i understood from your question. Pardon me if this is not what you are looking for :)

Comment: it work !!  if i want   4321(reverse number) - 1234(input number) what should i do?

Comment: could you be a bit more clear. Are you talking about a input that doesn't have any zeros?

Comment: ok you want to find the difference between the the reverse and input number?

Comment: if so you have to parse them into integer and then find the difference

Comment: You call `parseInt()`, as in: `String input = in.next(); String reverse = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString(); int result = Integer.parseInt(reverse) - Integer.parseInt(input);`

Comment: how to Integer.parseInt number.reverse()

Comment: my bad i was thinking about Integer.valueOf() method but somehow the first thing that came upon my mind was parse, sorry about that :)

Comment: FYI: You should verify that input is a number: `if (! number.matches("\\d+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a number: " + number);`

Comment: `Integer.valueOf()` returns an `Integer`. Use `parseInt()` (like I commented above), to prevent unnecessary boxing.

Comment: int b=Integer.valueOf(name.reverse().toString()); it not reverse number so let my output = 0

Comment: @Andreas Thanks again. But i don't understand the a autoboxing that you are talking about. i am a novice in java

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need to loop exactly 4 times. You should also guard against bad data, and you should print number as 4 digits:

```
if (num < 0 || num > 9999)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a 4-digit number: " + num);
int reverse = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++, num /= 10)
    reverse = reverse * 10 + num % 10;
System.out.printf("%04d%n", reverse);
```

Of course, you could also do it using String manipulation:

```
if (num < 0 || num > 9999)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a 4-digit number: " + num);
String reverse = new StringBuilder(String.format("%04d", num)).reverse().toString();
System.out.printf(reverse);
```

Both methods can be enhanced to support 5+ digits if needed.

**Followup**

Comment in answer by Ninth-tail:

> if i want 4321(reverse number) - 1234(input number) what should i do?

The first version above is best for that, since you already have the numbers, with minor change to retain original input:

```
if (input < 0 || input > 9999)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a 4-digit number: " + input);
int reverse = 0;
for (int i = 0, num = input; i < 4; i++, num /= 10)
    reverse = reverse * 10 + num % 10;
System.out.printf("Reverse: %04d%n", reverse);
System.out.printf("Difference: %04d%n", reverse - input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include "0044" and similar cases you should look at the input as a String. Whenever you need the number you can convert it to Integer. Try this:

```
public class ReverseNumber {

    static int reverse = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String num = "0044";
        String temp = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
        reverse = Integer.valueOf(temp);
        System.out.println(reverse);

    }

}
```

I hope it helps.